# jMeter: Restart loop only after the previous loop is complete

Tags: csv, jmeter, load-testing

I am running a load test using jMeter. With 10 concurrent threads. Loop count is forever.
The test data is fetched from a csv file. The csv file has only 10 entries. 
When the thread group is still processing 1 loop, jmeter starts the 2nd loop.

Therefore the test cases with same test data is running concurrently and issues are reported. I want jMeter to start the next loop only after all the threads in the previous loop have completed processing.

Is there a configuration for this. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you just use 1 Thread looped 10 times? Set the CSV to `Stop Thread on EOF` and not `Recycle on EOF` and you can even keep your Thread Group at `Forever`.

Comment: I do however need more that 1 thread to run for the load test. Konstantin Dobroliubov's answer below solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The highest element in your Jmeter tree (named Test Plan) has "Run thread groups consecutively (i.e. run groups one at a time)" option. Once enabled, thread groups will be implemented according to the order defined in your test plan: 1st group, then 2nd group, etc.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks Konstantin Dobroliubov.

Comment: Oops.. Spoke too soon. This didn't work. I have a single thread group. I am looping this thread group 10 times. I want the next loop to start after the previous loop has completed execution and all threads have returned.